# to_bytes function returning odd value

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I am having trouble with the to_bytes function of integer type. The values bigger than 18200000 are giving me a weird byte array as an output.

I am using python 3.5 on raspberry pi. The value is not exactly 18200000 but close.

The way I call the function is like this:

```
frequency = 20000000

print(frequency.to_bytes(7,byteorder='big'))
```

The expected result would be `b'\x01\x31\x2D\x00'`

What I get is `b'\x011-\x00'`.

Comment: They are the same string; Python just *displays* a byte as a printable ASCII character when possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know this fact. This is a side project to test embedded projects and I am still learning basic stuff like this.

Comment: ```print(frequency.to_bytes(7,byteorder='big').hex())``` will be your friend

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For bytes that are printable ASCII characters, python will display the corresponding character. `\x31` is the character `1`, and `\x2D` is `-`.